# differential opamp in positive feedback

Tags: positive-feedback

I am attaching the screenshot of differential op-amp with positive feedback(TLV9062),i am having the doubt ,is the output is same as input with all the same resistor values or any effect with positive feedback,can anyone explain? here i need differential to single ended output.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The circuit diagram is not complete....no negative fedback? There is an open path at the output....

Comment: Generally if you have an opamp circuit with positive feedback, the output will just slam to one of the rails like a comparator, or it will oscillate.   Which Is your intent?

Comment: actually i need differential to single ended output voltage at TLV9062 op-amp

Comment: I need output of amc1311 as same as Vin and this differential output changed to single ended using an op-amp,so can you please explain any  changes in this circuit for working as differential to single ended.

Answer (score 0):

Differential to single ended output op-amp:
[image: diff]

The generator and the two 1k resistors model the previous stage.

The same DC coupled is a bit more complicated:
[image: diffdc]

Comment: thank you, but i use amc1311 isolation op-amp,is it working with TLV9062 op-amp ?what modification are done in my circuit,can you please explain?

Comment: The isolation op-amp can remain as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

The (+) and (-) inputs should be swapped on the TLV9062  for it to function as a difference amplifier or differential to single-ended converter.

Also the resistor values are **way** too low. They should be more like 20K than 20 ohms.

Comment: I am attching the screenshots of my simulation can you explain the problem present  in that simulation?

Comment: I am replacing the tlv9062 with tlv2221 and changed the (+) and (-) terminals in opamp that time also i am getting the false output,what is the problem here, can you explain.

Comment: Please plot VOUTN as well and swap VOUTP and VOUTN.

Comment: After swaping the VOUTN and VOUTP also i am getting the opamp output as constant 3.3v at opamp and as well as at comparator.i am attaching the screenshots also.

Comment: The output at the TLV2221 should now be (VOUTP - VOUTN) but limited to 0/3.3V approximately. We need to see VOUTP and VOUTN on the same graph.

Comment: here we see the differential output (i connected the differential probe(red),so we see the VOUTP and VOUTN in single wave.

Comment: Okay, you're getting roughly the expected waveform but too low amplitude. Try getting rid of the capacitors C5 and C6.

Comment: I got the output,but it is in negative scale also but if i remove the -ve supply and connected to ground then negative signal clip at 0v,but i need 3.3v positive supply only what modification are done can anyone explain? i am attaching the screenshots of waveforms.

Comment: If you swap VOUTP & VOUTN you will get negative of the signal but it will still clip at 0V and 3.3V. Not sure what you are actually expecting.

Comment: I need 3.3V at positive scale only at opamp output for hat what modifications can i do?